# Is Azure Notifications Hub a deceased service?

Tags: azure-notificationhub

Two years ago, I barely managed to make this service work.

The documentation seems to be very dated, Microsoft isn't actively pushing this and the sample code Microsoft supplies is no longer using supported libraries.

Has anyone got access to or can they supply a valid sample Android/IOS sample code that uses the Azure notification Hub?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear that's been your experience. You can find an up-to-date sample Android and iOS applications in our GitHub repositories here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-android/tree/main/notification-hubs-sample-app-java

https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-ios/ (Several sample applications available at root level of repository)